# I want to add a void function to my stack class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am using stack method so i can add a container above the picture. However, to get the picture i am using a void function and stack doesn’t allow void functions it just allows widgets, so what can i do.

My code:

```
void gettingtheimage(CompoundEntity obj) {
    if (obj.images != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < obj.images.length; i++) {
        if (obj.images[i].mediumQualityImagePath != null) {
          this.images.add(getImageUrl(obj.images[i].mediumQualityImagePath));
        }
        if (obj.images[i].coverPhoto == true &&
            obj.images[i].mediumQualityImagePath != null) {
          this.coverImage = getImageUrl(obj.images[i].mediumQualityImagePath);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the void function to get the image.

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
                 gettingtheimage(obj),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7)),
                          color: Color(0xFFEB4D28),
                        ),
                        width: 100,
                        height: 25,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Sponsored",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: "Helvetica Neue",
                                fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                ]),
```

And this is my stack so it gives me an error that stack can’t take a void function.

Comment: I think you are a little confused. You are not using a "stack method", you are using the constructor of the Stack widget class to create a new Stack widget. And yes, that does not take void functions, why would it. Do you want to call the function before you build the Stack?

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68932294/13997210) answer hope your problem is solved

Comment: No, what i want is that the void function gets the image so i want to add a container above this image therefore, i am using stack as it allows me to put widgets above each other so i don’t know how can i solve the problem of the void function so i can make it work.

Comment: @AhmedNaeim you should call that method in the initState of that widget. If the widget isn't a StatefulWidget make it Stateful and call that method inside the initiate. Also calling that function inside the build method is bad. You need to keep your build method clean. Build method can run multiple times so that method will be called everytime the build method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have reason to call function middle of widget tree. Use `Builder` in this case.
To know more, visit [Builder-class.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html)

```
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              gettingtheimage(obj);
              return Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7)),
                      color: Color(0xFFEB4D28),
                    ),
                    width: 100,
                    height: 25,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Sponsored",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: "Helvetica Neue",
                            fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                    )),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `gettingtheimage(obj)` before constructor, after build method or in controller.

```
Widget build (...) {
  gettingtheimage(obj);
  return ... (
  ... : Stack(
    ...
```